# chapter and section overlayed in header - Any help?

Tags: header-footer

I could not fix an overlayed text in my document. I am not sure how to add space (and if it should work).
It would be a good idea to put chapters and sections headers in different pages (for example odd and even)but i don't know how to do it.

The image at the end shows the problem.

This **MWE** reproduces what i upload in the image:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}

\usepackage[headheight=18pt,a4paper, width=150mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm, bindingoffset=6mm, headsep=18pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[activate={true,nocompatibility},final,tracking=true,kerning=true,spacing=true,factor=1100,stretch=10,shrink=10]{microtype}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength\parskip{1em plus 10pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\emergencystretch=1em
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}

\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{50pt}{1.3ex plus .2ex}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Estado del arte}
foo
\section{Consideraciones termodinámica}
foo

foo

foo
foo


foo

foo

foo

foo

foo

foo
foo

foo
foo



foo



foo









fo






fo








fo





fi+







fo



fo
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `! Undefined control sequence. l.15 \titleformat` please fix the example

Comment: @DavidCarlisle i edit now

Comment: You probably should have section title on evenpages, and chapter titles on odd pages.

Comment: @Bernard that is a good idea but i couldn't

Comment: I guess you still haven't read any basic material and *learn* on the way, but you can also have a shortened title for the header and the table of contents with -> `\chapter[short]{Long title}`

Comment: @Johannes_B i am not sure that's the best way to learn latex. Thank you for the advice anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a code for a new pagestyle, using the tools from `titlesec` with option `pagestyles`, in the place of `fancyhdr`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside, spanish]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[headheight=18pt, a4paper, width=150mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm, bindingoffset=6mm, headsep=18pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[activate={true,nocompatibility},final,tracking=true,kerning=true,spacing=true,factor=1100,stretch=10,shrink=10]{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}

\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{50pt}{1.3ex plus .2ex}

\newpagestyle{mystyle}{%
\headrule\footrule
\sethead[\small\itshape\thesection.\enspace\MakeUppercase{\sectiontitle}][][]{}{\small\itshape\MakeUppercase{\chaptername~\thechapter.\enspace \chaptertitle}}{}
\setfoot{}{\thepage}{}
}
\pagestyle{mystyle}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Estado del arte}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Consideraciones termodinámica}

\lipsum[2-12]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It returns an error:                                                                                                          ! Package titlesec Error: Incompatible package.
See the titlesec package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.253 \newcommand\headrule{\setheadrule{.4\p@}}
Titlesec cannot continue defining its own macros because
\headrule is already used by other package, the class
or the document.

Comment: I was doing something wrong, it works!